# Calling an external C function (in a shared lib) from Perl with Inline/C does not work

Tags: c, perl

The code is more or less stolen from the page of the author:
https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Inline-C/lib/Inline/C/Cookbook.pod
but does not give the expected results:

```
use Inline C => Config =>
           enable => autowrap =>
           LIBS => "-lmylib ";
use Inline C => <<'END_OF_C_CODE';

extern char *sharedFun(char *);

void greet(char* name) {
  printf("Hello %s!\n", name);
}


char *func(char* name) {
  static char mystr[1024];
  char *p;

  strcpy(mystr, "string: ");
  p = sharedFun(name);
  strcpy(mystr, p);

  return(mystr);
}

END_OF_C_CODE

greet('Hello World');
greet(42);
$p = func("foobar");
print $p, "\n";
```

The result of the execution is:

```
nm libmylib.so | grep shared
000000000000056a T sharedFun
file libmylib.so
libmylib.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (FreeBSD), dynamically linked, not stripped


$ perl inline.pl
Hello Hello World!
Hello 42!
/usr/home/guru/Perl/_Inline/lib/auto/inline_pl_9404/inline_pl_9404.so: Undefined symbol "sharedFun"
```

and I checked with `strace`: the shared lib `libmylib.so` is not searched for.
Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the problem is: The required shared lib must exist in the **first run** of `perl inline.pl` (when the connectors get compiled). If it is not there, later it is never search for:

```
$ perl inline.pl
Hello Hello World!
Hello 42!
/usr/home/guru/Perl/_Inline/lib/auto/inline_pl_8196/inline_pl_8196.so: Undefined symbol "sharedFun"
$ clang -shared -o libmylib.so mylib.c
$ ls -l libmylib.so
-rwxr-xr-x  1 guru  wheel  5546  4 nov.  22:23 libmylib.so
$ perl inline.pl
Hello Hello World!
Hello 42!
/usr/home/guru/Perl/_Inline/lib/auto/inline_pl_8196/inline_pl_8196.so: Undefined symbol "sharedFun"


$ rm -r _Inline
$ perl inline.pl
Hello Hello World!
Hello 42!
foobar
```

We can close this thread.

Answer (score 4):

I think the lib is searched for but isn't found and therefore the symbols aren't loaded.

From the documentation you may be able to provide the path to the library: 
`LIBS => '-L/your/lib/path -lyourlib';`

Comment: Tezrig is on to something. I get identical output when I haven't even created a `libmylib.so` file. Another idea is to set your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment so that it can find your `.so` file.

Comment: I tested this, and it works fine here (without having to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH)

Comment: Before raising the issue here, I experimented as well with `-L ...` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. The real solution is: creating the shared lib **before** starting the Perl for the 1st time for the script with the inline code.