# Calling function of an external Inline C block from another perl modules Inline C block

Tags: perl, inline-c

I am looking for a way to call a function of an Inline C block present in a perl file from another file's Inline C block.

I have this perl file that contains the get_instrument_price function inside an Inline C block

```
package Dev::Instrument::Price;

use warnings 'all';
use strict;

use Inline C => <<'__END_OF_C__';

int get_instrument_price(int type)
{ return 154; }

__END_OF_C__
```

There's another file that should make a call to the above file to get the instrument price

```
package Dev::Instument::Detail;

use warnings 'all';
use strict;

use Inline C => <<'__END_OF_C__';

extern int *get_instrument_price(int type);

int get_instrument_detail(int type)
{ 
    # some code
    int instrument_price = get_instrument_price(type);
    # some more code
}

__END_OF_C__
```

I have tried using `LIBS => '-L/_Inline/lib/auto'` as mentioned in the references below that didn't work for me.

Took references from:

1. [Calling an external C function (in a shared lib) from Perl with Inline/C does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53117515/calling-an-external-c-function-in-a-shared-lib-from-perl-with-inline-c-does-no)
2. https://www.foo.be/docs/tpj/issues/vol5_3/tpj0503-0005.html
3. https://metacpan.org/dist/Inline-C/view/lib/Inline/C/Cookbook.pod

Comment: Your first snippet creates a *Perl* sub named `get_instrument_price`. Calling Perl subs is documented in perlcall. To call directly as a C function, build a DLL/SO used by both

Comment: *"tried using LIBS => '-L/_Inline/lib/auto'"* Since Inline::C generates two independent .so libraries I think you would have to link the one that uses the extern function with `-Wl,-rpath,..` to set runtime path for the linker. I tested it now by using `Inline C => config => lddlflags => $lddflags;` with `$lddflags` equal to the config lddlflags plus the location of the second shared object plus `-Wl,-rpath,..` to the same location, but it still fails to find that extern function at run time.

Answer (score 3):

A workaround is to split the common C functions into a separate library, for example:

**libinstrument/instrument.c**:

```
#include "instrument.h"
int get_instrument_price(int type)
{
    return 154;
}
```

**libinstrument/instrument.h**:

```
int get_instrument_price(int type);
```

**lib/Dev/Instrument/Detail.pm**:

```
package Dev::Instrument::Detail;
use FindBin;
my $lib_dir;
BEGIN {
    $lib_dir = $FindBin::RealBin . '/libinstrument';
}
use warnings 'all';
use strict;
#use Inline Config => build_noisy => 1, clean_after_build => 0, print_info => 1;
use Inline C => config => libs => "-L$lib_dir -linstrument";
use Inline C => config => inc => '-I' . $lib_dir;
use Inline C => <<'__END_OF_C__';

#include "instrument.h"
int get_instrument_detail(int type)
{
    // some code
    int instrument_price = get_instrument_price(type);
    // some more code
    return instrument_price + 1;
}
__END_OF_C__
1;
```

**lib/Dev/Instrument/Price.pm**:

```
package Dev::Instrument::Price;
use warnings 'all';
use strict;

use FindBin;
my $lib_dir;
BEGIN {
    $lib_dir = $FindBin::RealBin . '/libinstrument';
}
use Inline C => config => libs => "-L$lib_dir -linstrument";
use Inline C => config => inc => '-I' . $lib_dir;
#use Inline Config => build_noisy => 1, clean_after_build => 0, print_info => 1;
use Inline C => <<'__END_OF_C__';
#include "instrument.h"

int foo(int type)
{
    int instrument_price = get_instrument_price(type);
    return instrument_price + 2;
}
__END_OF_C__
1;
```

**p.pl**:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use v5.38;
use lib './lib';
use Dev::Instrument::Price;
use Dev::Instrument::Detail;

say Dev::Instrument::Price::foo(1);
say Dev::Instrument::Detail::get_instrument_detail(1);
```

**Compile the common library**:

```
$ gcc -shared -fPIC -o libinstrument.so instrument.c
```

**Output**:

```
$ perl p.pl
156
155
```